# python regex, repetion on subgroup

Tags: python, regex

I am currently working on mastering the skill of regex in Python. In both I am not an expert. Maybe I used the wrong regex terms and that is why I did not find my answer. If that is the case, apologize.

I have created a teststring and a two different regex-es accoording to the code below:

```
teststring = "This is just a string of literal text with some 0987654321 and an issue in it"

reg = re.compile(r"([0-9]{3})*",re.DEBUG)
outSearch = reg.search(teststring)

print "Test with ([0-9]{3})*"
if outSearch:
    print "groupSearch = " + outSearch.group()
    print

reg = re.compile(r"([0-9]{3})+",re.DEBUG)
outSearch = reg.search(teststring)

print "Test with ([0-9]{3})+"
if outSearch:
    print "groupSearch = " + outSearch.group()
```

This test-cde results in the output below:

```
max_repeat 0 4294967295
  subpattern 1
    max_repeat 3 3
      in
        range (48, 57)
Test with ([0-9]{3})*
groupSearch = 

max_repeat 1 4294967295
  subpattern 1
    max_repeat 3 3
      in
        range (48, 57)
Test with ([0-9]{3})+
groupSearch = 098765432
```

Now the interesting part: I would expect both regex would came back with the same result. eg, the result I've got with ([0-9]{3})+. When I use ([0-9]{3})*, the regex matches the teststring but the outSearch.group() is empty. Can someone explain me why that is?

btw. Both regex have no practical use, I am just trying to understand how regex works in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Your first code is using `*` to repeat - that means it'll match *zero or more* occurrences of the previous group. But when you use `+` to repeat, that requires *at least one* occurrence. So, a regular expression containing *only one optional group* will first match the *very beginning* of the string, and match no characters at all if the group does not accept the first character of the string. This will be clearer if you check the `start()` and `end()` of each match:

```
teststring = "some 0987654321"
reg = re.compile(r"([0-9]{3})*",re.DEBUG)
outSearch = reg.search(teststring)

print("Test with ([0-9]{3})*")
if outSearch:
    print ("groupSearch = " + outSearch.group() + ' , ' + str(outSearch.start()) + ' , ' + str(outSearch.end()))

reg = re.compile(r"([0-9]{3})+",re.DEBUG)
outSearch = reg.search(teststring)

print("Test with ([0-9]{3})+")
if outSearch:
    print ("groupSearch = " + outSearch.group() + ' , ' + str(outSearch.start()) + ' , ' + str(outSearch.end()))
```

Output:

```
Test with ([0-9]{3})*
groupSearch =  , 0 , 0

Test with ([0-9]{3})+
groupSearch = 098765432 , 5 , 14
```

(The first regex's match started at index 0 and ended at index 0 - the empty string)

This is not unique to Python - this is expected behavior pretty much anywhere:

https://regex101.com/r/BwMWTq/1

(click through to other languages - see how all languages, not just Python, start and end their match at index 0)

Comment: I would like to add, that it is helpful to print also the re.findall() method. Then you can see all occurences found under the first regex (results might also be interesting)

Answer (score 0):

In Regex:

- `+`: Matches *one or more* of the preceding token
- `*`: Matches *zero or more* of the preceding token

Now:

- `([0-9]{3})+` will match one or more time (`+`) 3 consecutive digits (`[0-9]{3}`), hence it contains 9 digits in the primary matched group i.e. group 0 -- 098765432, ignoring the last 1 of 0987654321 i.e. the match spans from index 48 to 56 (`teststring[48:57]`). You can check this with `span()` method of `SRE_Match` object too e.g. `outSearch.span()`
- `([0-9]{3})*` will match zero or more time (`*`) 3 consecutive digits; as it can match zero time also, it matches the start of the string and stops there, giving empty string as the primary matched group output i.e. the match spans from string index 0 to 0